# How to plot "$f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ on $(0,0) \times (1,1)$?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Hello Friends Thanks for your time.

Please help in plotting $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ on a unit square with TikZ.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a very basic approach derived from an example in the [pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) manual.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[colorbar]
      \addplot3[surf,faceted color=blue,samples=15,domain=0:1,y domain=0:1]{x^2+y^2};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Desired modifications are left to the interested reader.

---

[image]